# Sync closure needs to wait for async code

Tags: swift, async-await

I am developing an app that uses [MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter) to control audio reproduction from the lock screen.

The code is inside a @MainActor view-model, part of a SwiftUI project.

The initial code that I need to incorporate is:

```
            commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
            commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
                    if !self.isPlaying {
                        self.playOrPause()
                        return .success
                    }
                    return .commandFailed
            }
```

I have tried this:

```
            commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
            commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
                return await MainActor.run {
                    if !self.isPlaying {
                        self.playOrPause()
                        return .success
                    }
                    return .commandFailed
                }
            }
```

But still it doesn't compile.

I understand why: the callback method is not marked to be async. Still it expects a value, that I can return only from async code, because I need to wait to re-enter into the main thread.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ask for a sync function to wait for an async. You can have  however an async function receiving the returned values from other async closures using `withCheckedContinuation()`.

In your case, this is how it might work:

```
        let isSuccessfullyCompleted: Bool = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in

            commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
            commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
                    if !self.isPlaying {
                        self.playOrPause()
                        continuation.resume(returning: true)
                    } else {
                        continuation.resume(returning: false)
                    }
            }        
        }
```

With the code above, `isSuccessfullyCompleted` will wait for the closure to complete and return a value, before resuming the code. The variable doesn't need to be a `Bool`, but the code above needs to run in an async function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still it is not working - and it doesn't compile either.

Here I don't need an async setting of the playCommand.

What I really need, is that the sync delegate is able to wait for the return value from the async code.
The async code is needed only because my view-model bound to the SwiftUI view and so it is decoraeted with @MainActor.

In C#, I would have added a .Result to wait synchnously for an async result (still ugly).

I don't know how to solve it here, even if I think that I am following the correct patterns, with MVVM and actors...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to have a sync code waiting...